# Can not add class dynamically in a tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help.I could not add class dynamically using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
$.each(obj.cid, function() {
      $("#ulCategory").append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat("+this.id+","+this+")'>" + this.name +</li>");
});

function savesubcat(id,$this){
  $($this).addClass("active");
  $($this).siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

Here I need to add active class on clicked anchor tag but in my way its not happening like this.Please help me.

Comment: When you have code which manipulates the HTML it's best to show said HTML along with the JS code.

Comment: First of all you have made a syntax mistake, that might cause the error

Comment: And $($this) is wrong. It should be $this only

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that you're not wrapping the string value in quotes in the function call. The second problem is that, from the context, `this` is an object. Concatenating an object to a string isn't going to work as you expect.

To fix this it would be far better to use an unobtrusive delegated event handler. That way you get the `this` reference within the handler function anyway, so you don't need to pass it. All you would need to do is put the `id` from the object in a `data` attribute so it can be read within the event handler.

Also note that `this` will refer to the `a` element which has no siblings. To add the class to the other `a` elements you need to traverse the DOM to the parent `ul` and then `find()` them. Try this:

Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  cid: [{
    id: 'abc',
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 'xyz',
    name: 'bar'
  }]
};

var li = $.map(obj.cid, function(o) {
  return '<li><a href="#" data-id="' + o.id + '">' + o.name + '</a></li>';
});

$('#ulCategory').append(li.join('')).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $a = $(this);
  console.log($a.data('id'));
  
  $a.addClass('active').closest('ul').find('a').not($a).removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory"></ul>
```